# Switch text and background colors on click

Tags: jquery

I have four circles each with a unique background color and a span inside which is white.
When the user clicks on each circle I want that circle to switch background and span color, or in other words, I want the background color to be set for span, and background to become white.

My code does this correctly, but when I click on any other circle I want that circle to have white background and colored span while the previous circle is back to default (white span, colored background).

The jQuery:

```
$("#fifthcircleholder li").click(function () {
    var currentspan = $(this).find("span");
    var allspans = $("#fifthcircleholder li").find("span");

    $(this).find("span").css({
        color: $(this).css("background-color")
    });
    $(allspans).not(currentspan).css({
        "color": "#fff"
    });
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "#ffffff"
    })

    var found = $("#fifthcircleholder li");
    if (found.css("background-color") == "#fff") {
        $(this).find("span").css({
            "background-color": $(this).css("color")
        });
    }


});
```

The HTML:

```
<ul id="fifthcircleholder">
    <li id="fifthc1"><span>blah blah</span></li>
    <li id="fifthc2"><span>blah</span></li>
    <li id="fifthc3"><span>blah</span></li>
    <li id="fifthc4"><span>blah</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you not reduce all that to just giving the "active" circle an "active" class, and create CSS-rules to affect this instead?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård Well, not really, the number of items and their colors are going to be dynamic

Comment: That doesn't need to matter. You could give all your circleholders a class, say "circleholder". Then you do $(".circleholder").removeClass("active"); $("#fifthcircleholder").addClass("active"); Then it wouldn't matter how many circleholders you have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a crack at it, hopefully it will help:

http://jsfiddle.net/jnLMy/

HTML:

```
<ul id="fifthcircleholder">
<li id="fifthc1"><span>blah blah</span></li>
<li id="fifthc2"><span>blah</span></li>
<li id="fifthc3"><span>blah</span></li>
<li id="fifthc4"><span>blah</span></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
li { width:100px; padding:20px; cursor:pointer; text-align:center; }
li span { background:#fff; }

#fifthc1 { background:lime; }
#fifthc2 { background:yellow; }
#fifthc3 { background:orange; }
#fifthc4 { background:blue; }
```

JS:

```
$("#fifthcircleholder li").click(function() {

    $('#fifthcircleholder li').each(function() {
        if( hexc( $(this).css('background-color') ) === '#ffffff' ){
            $(this).css('background-color', $(this).find('span').css('background-color') );
            $(this).find('span').css('background-color', '#ffffff' );
        }        
    });    

    $(this).find('span').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color') );
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
});

function hexc(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
   return '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

Comment: You Rock! this is what you call a perfect answer.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script: http://jsfiddle.net/YAJma/

```
$("#fifthcircleholder li").click(function() {
    $('span').css({"color":"black", "background":"white"});
    $('span',this).css({"color":"red", "background":"yellow"});
});​
```

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for a way to switch the colors using variables, and please note that each circle has a different color, the same goes to span when it's active.

Comment: @Sonyflat where and how are you setting the colors initially for the circles?

Comment: @wirey currently colors come from external css file, but later they will be retrieved from cms. that is why I'm looking for a way to switch the colors using variables, so it works with dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fifthcircleholder li").click(function() {
        //reset potentially previously set colors:
        $('#fifthcircleholder li').each(function(){
            //child span's color
            var spanColor=$('span',this).css('background-color');
            if(spanColor!='white'){
                $(this).css('background-color',spanColor);
                $('span',this).css('background-color','white');
            }
        });
        //now for the colors of the currently clicked li
        var liColor=$(this).css('background-color');
        $('span').css('background-color',liColor);
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it is in right direction but the moment you click on a circle all backgrounds go away.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kBKjZ/1/